# Add Attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to add attribute src on source tag inside of video tag using a javascript?
I have tried many methods like:

```
$("#source-tag-id").setAttribute('src', 'attribute-value');
```

```
document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].setAttribute("class", "democlass");
```

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];
var att = document.createAttribute("class");
att.value = "democlass";
h1.setAttributeNode(att);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add a `src` attribute to an `h1` element? That won't work.

Comment: @terrymorse there is no such thing in the OP code

Comment: @kosmos Thanks, I see that now.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery uses `.attr()`, so the correct is `$("#source-tag-id").attr('src', 'attribute-value')`.

```
// wrong ✗
$("#source-tag-id").setAttribute('src', 'attribute-value');

// ok ✓
$("#source-tag-id").attr('src', 'attribute-value');

// vanilla ✓
document.querySelector('#source-tag-id').src = 'atribute-value';
```

With vanilla js you can access classes through .classList property, i.e:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].classList.add("democlass");
```

Check documentations:

- https://api.jquery.com/attr/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList